# Using grep to filter files doesn't output all the lines

Tags: bash, filter, grep

I've been working with grep to try to filter a file by strings contained in another file. The problem is that I'm working with millions on records and some one grep is not getting all of the lines.

I've export the results with to two files:

1. contains the lines that match those strings
2. contains the lines that doesn't match those strings

The sum of both outputs is not the original amount of lines

```
[ ]$ grep -vwF -f functions.csv whole-data-slice_statement2.csv > output1.csv$
[ ]$ grep -wF -f functions.csv whole-data-slice_statement2.csv > output2.csv$
[ ]$ wc -l whole-data-slice_statement2.csv$
4278709 whole-data-slice_statement2.csv
[ ]$ wc -l output1.csv$
106692 output1.csv
[ ]$ wc -l output2.csv$
2326396 output2.csv
```

Could some one help me to understand if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: you need to edit-- output1.csv contains the lines that do NOT match, and output2.csv has the matching lines.  Your question currently has that reversed, but I'm assuming it's a typo and not a logic error.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `grep` commands and your expectations for them, so I'm inclined to think that there is something odd about your data that triggers this behavior.  Note that `grep`'s documented behavior is predicated on the input being a *text* file.

Comment: Is it possible there is another process writing to these files?

Comment: do you get different numbers when you first use `tr -d "\r"`?

Comment: Saint. You are correct. I did number them wrong they should be inverted. There is no way that other process is writing to those files. This has been done in a terminal with many other output names that i randomly select. I still get the same results. I don't know what tr -d "\r" would do but will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it seems some invalid characters were causing the grep command to abort and not let it finish with the complete set. I've remove them and everything is working now.
'grep -P "[\x80-\xFF]" file.xml'

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can duplicate this is to have a null character in my whole-data-slice_statement2.csv file.  When it has a special character in it, `file` will return "data". Do...
`file whole-data-slice_statement2.csv`

See if it says "whole-data-slice_statement2.csv: data".  You can use `tr` to clean the file.

edit: this may work to clean the nulls not at the EOF.
`tr -cd '[:graph:]\n\t ' $file >$tmp_file`

Comment: `[]$catwhole-data-slice_statement.csv|tr-d"\r">tmp2
[]$ls-ltr
total1959156
-rw-rw-r--.1 1003078989May1918:34whole-data-slice_statement.csv
-rw-rw-r--.1 1003078989May2214:04tmp2
[]$grep-vwFi-ffunctions.csvwhole-data-slice_statement.csv>output1.csv
grep:functions.csv:Nosuchfileordirectory
[]$grep-vwFi-ffunctions.csvwhole-data-slice_statement.csv>output1.csv
[]$wc-loutput1.csv
106692output1.csv
[]$grep-wFi-ffunctions.csvwhole-data-slice_statement.csv>output2.csv[]$wc-loutput2.csv
2326396output2.csv
[]$ wc -l whole-data-slice_statement.csv 
4278709 whole-data-slice_statement.csv`

Comment: Miguel, you misunderstood me.  I said you have a `null` character, and to do a `file` on it to see if it returns data.  You removed `Windows carriage` returns, and did an ls on it?  Do a `file` and tell me if it's text or data.  See my edit above for more help.

Comment: Thanks. I have been playing with the files and did something similar to clean it. 'tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < slice-1.csv > slice-1_clean.csv' It worked and I created a file without the null character. I'll try your tip as soon as I have access to the data again.